# Pandas and correlation, cant make them work

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matrix, error-handling, correlation

I am trying to generate a correlation matrix using corr()

from datascience import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plots
plots.style.use ("fivethirtyeight")

premier = Table.read_table("Documents//Stats PL1.csv")

```
premier.corr()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-9531b81a92c8> in <module>
----> 1 premier.corr()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datascience\tables.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    233         else:
    234             msg = "'{0}' object has no attribute '{1}'".format(type(self).__name__, attr)
--> 235             raise AttributeError(msg)
    236 
    237     ####################

AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'corr'
```

I already review all the pandas instructions,  installed and unistalled all the packages, this is not the first function  that fail (the other one was df.to_excel) but didn´t solved it either
Realy dont know where to look for an answer, thanks for all the help!

Comment: You can convert the table to a dataframe like table_data=pd.DataFrame(premier) and then run table_data.corr(). Let me know if that helps, I will add this to answer section then.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried but didn´t work,  the df was working already, is the corr function that  doesn´t seems to work,  this is the error message AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'corr'